# Android tethering: Mac doesn't detect new network interface

Tags: network, usb, macos, tethering, android

I am trying to share my 3G internet connection from my Nexus 4 running Android 5.1.1 with my Macbook Pro running *macOS Sierra 10.12*. Using an USB cable (aka USB Tethering). After connecting the phone and turning on the *USB tethering* option, When I go to *"Open Network Preferences"* from the network icon in the status bar, I don't see my phone listed as expected to proceed with the configuration.

Although, I do see my phone in **About this mac -> Overview -> System Report -> Hardware -> USB**. The *Android File Transfer* app opens when I connect it to the computer, and it closes when I turn on tethering.

I tried installing HoRNDIS, and even restarting afterwards, but didn't solve. Tried to play around the *USB Debugging* option as well without success.

My broadband allows tethering since I can do it over Wifi and Bluetooth really straightforward.

Is there a specific set of Sierra native steps to set up a generic USB network interface that supports android 5.1.1?

Comment: ["Heads up: HoRNDIS does NOT yet work on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)! "](http://joshuawise.com/horndis#available_versions) -  How is it supposed to work with Sierra then?

Comment: My question is about tethering in general, and I just wanted to make clear that I even tested HoRNDIS, before someone suggest.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this link to some software that works on Sierra I found on a YouTube video. It is only a trial, easily reinstalled though.

http://download.clockworkmod.com/tether/tether-mac.zip